# How i can use the function encrypt in one consult update

Tags: postgresql, update

I'm trying to duplicate a column, but I would like to encrypt it with not very high data value, and I was able to do it, well, just the first part.

```
CREATE TABLE probeta (
  id int primary key,
  numero_documento varchar ,
  documento_prefijo varchar,
  numero_documento_crypt varchar,
  documento_prefijo_crypt varchar 
);
```

| id | num_doc | Doc | Doc encrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 11 |  |
| 2 | 22222 | 22 |  |
| 3 | 33333 | 33 |  |
| 4 | 44444 | 44 |  |
| 5 | 55555 | 55 |  |

With this basic query, I can do what I need

```
UPDATE probeta SET numero_documento_crypt =(pgp_sym_encrypt(numero_documento::varchar, 'psw','compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes'))
where 1=1;
```

| id | num_doc | Doc | Doc encrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 11 | \xc30d0407030248ab17f709+120 |
| 2 | 22222 | 22 | \xc30d04070302abd258de7c+120 |
| 3 | 33333 | 33 | \xc30d0407030298735de291+120 |
| 4 | 44444 | 44 | \xc30d0407030210d81eb985+120 |
| 5 | 55555 | 55 | \xc30d040703026cdab3d82f+120 |

but

The length of the encrypted field is very long, about 140 characters.

When I try to do it as follows:

```
UPDATE probeta SET numero_documento_crypt = encrypt(numero_documento, 'key', 'aes')
where 1=1;
```

this to try to decrease the size of the field, but I have not succeeded.

The idea of ​​the process is to deliver encrypted data, but, when you need to know what value an encrypted data means, I can answer it, so do not use one-way encryption.

i try whit this:

UPDATE probeta SET numero_documento_crypt =crypt('numero_documento', gen_salt('des')) where 1=1;

And this is the result:

| id | num_doc | Doc | Doc encrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 11 | JiiU/WaYnqUwc |
| 2 | 22222 | 22 | C7W4f2lpkSKbI |
| 3 | 33333 | 33 | 7DqjVN0kbzlI2 |
| 4 | 44444 | 44 | m5psBwH03F./I |
| 5 | 55555 | 55 | skn3VAeCnXqA2 |

the doc_encrypt is short, and is unique, this solve my problem, butttt, again, the problem in this case is, that I cannot decipher that value, because it does not receive any seeds.

The idea of ​​this encryption is to pass only the encrypted data to a user, but when, when I need to know what value it refers to, I can decipher it.

Thanks to all who gave their opinion, I hope I have corrected what they required.

Could someone give me an opinion?

Comment: Could you please not use images for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). What do you mean by `but I would like to encrypt it with not very high data value,`? Could you please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your table, sample data and your desired result.

Comment: Of course, in one moment edit my post.

Comment: Please go to dbfiddle.uk and CREATE **your** tables and type in **your** data. Less chance of typo errors, no duplication of effort by those trying to answer and a single source of truth! Help us to help you!

Comment: https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1943

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to duplicate a column, but I would like to encrypt it with not very high data value

If the Data is not "high value", then why do you want to encrypt it?

> The length of the encrypted field is very long, about 140 characters.

This is *perfectly normal*.
What makes you think that this is a problem?

> The idea of ​​the process is to deliver encrypted data, but, when you need to know what value an encrypted data means, I can answer it

I suspect that the Application you're writing that will make this Data available to Users will *also* need to be able to decrypt it (and possibly re-encrypt it as well).

If your Users really have *no way* of ever accessing the Data, then use the "Most Secure Data Protection of All"(TM) - don't store it!

Comment: Wait, let me understand something, I want to encrypt a value, a very large piece of data, just that, but your logic tells me just not to do it?

It may be a simple college experiment, does that have a problem?

Comment: Encrypting data needs space to store it in (it's /always/ larger than the original) and processing time to do the encryption/decryption.  If you don't need to, why waste the time and effort?  Having encrypted this Data, what are you going to /do/ with it?  If you intend to read it back and put it in front of a User (through your Application) then your Application needs to be able to decrypt it.  If you don't intend for the user to /ever/ see it, why should you store it /at all/, encrypted or not?